# How do you hide a div border for mobile divices?

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, border

I'm designing a responsive website and I'm having trouble hiding a right border that divides the content side of a page from the sidebar. The border is on the right site of a div tag and I want to hide the border when the screen shrinks down to a mobile size. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best practices in responsive mobile web design, the best is to use what are called media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries. My favorite resource about this is here, written by Shay Howe: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

The idea is that your CSS will "detect" the size of the browser and apply CSS rules based on particular sizes of displays.

To do this, make sure that in your  tags in the HTML header that you add the following line:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
 height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

And then you can use media queries to "detect" the size of the display like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .element {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Media queries** allow you to change the properties of your styles depending on things like screen size, resolution or similar.

Simply write a media query and put your conditional styles inside of it. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .element {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

While this works fine, it's usally a better idea to approach mobile first. When writing CSS mobile first, your base CSS is for small devices, while you add rules for larger screens through media queries. Simply change the `max-width` in the media query to `min-width` and use a reverse logic when writing CSS will do the trick.

Here are two articles on media queries if you need further information: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).